# Laravel 4 - Password reminder errors not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im following the Laravel 4 docs in regards to the password reset functions.

The first bit seems to be working, except for the fact that im not seeing any error or success messages in my view.

I have used the controller that comes with laravel .. This is what i have in the controller.

```
switch ($response = Password::remind(Input::only('email')))
{
    case Password::INVALID_USER:
        return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));
    case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
        return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
}
```

and the following is what i have in my view.

```
@if (Session::has('error'))
    {{ trans(Session::get('reason')) }}
@elseif (Session::has('success'))
    An email with the password reset has been sent.
@endif
```

Also, can anyone tell me how to see what validation rules the password reminder has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
return Redirect::back()->with('status', Lang::get($response));
```

to

```
return Redirect::back()->with('success', Lang::get($response));
```

and change

```
{{ trans(Session::get('reason')) }}
```

to

```
{{ trans(Session::get('error')) }}
```

Comment: Now its displaying errors - preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array .... It was working before, it just wasnt relaying error messages back to the view